# Implementation of Queue using Linkedlist in Java

Tags: java, beginner, linked-list, queue

Can someone please review my code? Is it the correct implementation of a queue? If not, please give suggestions on how to implement it using a linked list.

```
class Queue
{
Node front,rear;

class Node
{
    int data;
    Node next;

    public Node(int d)
    {
        data=d;
        next=null;
    }
}

void enqueue(int new_data)
{
    Node new_node=new Node(new_data);

    if(front==null)
    {
        new_node.next=front;
        front=new_node;
        rear=front;
    }
    else if(rear.next==null)
    {
        rear.next=new_node;
        rear=rear.next;
    }
    System.out.println(rear.data+"\t Enqueued");
}

Node dequeue()
{
 if(front==null && rear==null) 
 { 
System.out.println("\t Queue is Empty"); 
  return null;
 }
    else    {
    Node temp=front;
    front=temp.next;
    temp.next=null;
    System.out.println(temp.data+"\t Dequeued");
if(front==null)
    { rear=front; }

    System.out.println(front +" "+ rear);
    return temp;
    }
}



public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Queue q=new Queue();
    q.enqueue(1);
    q.enqueue(2);
    q.enqueue(3);
    q.enqueue(4);

    q.dequeue();
    q.dequeue();


}
}
```

Comment: As @forsvarir mentioned, dequing from an empty queue can be problematic: in this case "front" will be null, causing an NPE (I think the rest of the function should be put to an else-block). Also, dequeue, should return an int, with the data that it read, otherwise, as forsavir hinted, it is not possible to read out the data.

Comment: And one more thing: it would be nice, for the case that the queue gets empty, that you also take care to null out "rear", to not have a dangling reference (for "front" this happens "automatically").

Comment: @Attilio Please refrain from reviewing code in comments. If you have a suggestion, please write an answer, even if it's short.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Formatting**

Your indentation is all over the place.  Using a consistent form of indenting that reflects the scoping of statements makes your code much easier to read and makes bugs easier to spot.

**Consistency**

Be consistent with your interface.  You define `enqueue` in terms of the data item that is to be stored in the queue.  This is good, because it hides the implementation.  However, you define `dequeue` as returning a `Node`.  This is bad, `Node` is an implementation detail, there's no reason for the caller to need to know it exists.  `dequeue` should instead be returning an `int` (as this is the type stored in the queue).

**Print statements**

Your print statements don't belong in your queue.  Part of the reason that you originally submitted code that didn't allow access to the values stored in the queue is because you put the print statements within it.  Separate the concerns of your classes and test the boundaries.  If you had originally tried to write your print statements in your `main` is would have become clear that you needed dequeue to return something in order for you to be able to print it.

**Mains don't belong in collections**

Your main method doesn't belong in the Queue.  It's not part of the Queue, it's part of your test harness.  You should put it in a different class.  This will help to enforce the boundaries between what is the Queue's responsibilities and what is not the Queue's responsibilities.

**Returns & Elses**

Where possible you want to avoid nesting statements too far.  In your dequeue, you're doing this:

```
if(front==null && rear==null) 
{ 
    System.out.println("\t Queue is Empty"); 
    return null;
}
else {
```

This creates a layer of nesting for the else statement.  You don't need the else.  When the `if` condition is matched, you return from the function.  The only way you get past the statement is if the condition didn't match, so the else is redundant.

**Redundant checks**

In enqueue you perform:

```
else if(rear.next==null)
```

You don't have an else condition for this check, and if this condition is triggered, it means that `rear` isn't pointing at the end of the queue and you've got something very wrong with your collection.  Either remove the `if` check, since it can't happen, or throw an exception when it does, don't just pretend everything is all right.

Comment: thnx forsvarir. for pointing and explaining, i will always keep these concepts in my mind when coding.